# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException in a Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, arraylist, collections, iterator

EDIT: I understand my mistake. I don't why but I was thinking that after the `previousItems.add(p);` is executed it was going out from the `for loop`. I've solved by adding a `break`

Other questions about this Exception didn't help me to get a solution.

I have a `Servlet` that is called when I add an item in the cart from another page.

I have an `ArrayList<Product>` and I iterate through the List to check if the same Product that I'm trying to add in already in the list. If it's already there I update its quantity otherwise I add the new Product in the List.

Everything is fine if add always the same Product, the Exception occurs when I add a different Product. So I think the problem in the code is after the `else` (commented with "This"), because it's executed if the Product is different.

```
@WebServlet(name = "AddCart", urlPatterns = {"/AddCart"})
public class AddCart extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        ArrayList<Product> previousItems = (ArrayList<Product>) session.getAttribute("previousItems");
        Product p = (Product) session.getAttribute("currentProduct");
        if (previousItems == null) {
            previousItems = new ArrayList<Product>();
        }

            if (p != null) {
                if (previousItems.size()>0) {
                    for (Product p1 : previousItems) {
                        if (p1.getId() == p.getId()) {
                            p1.addQuantity();
                        } else { //This
                            previousItems.add(p);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    previousItems.add(p);
                }
            }

        session.setAttribute("previousItems", previousItems);
        response.sendRedirect("cart.jsp");
    }
}
```

I've also tried to remove the `synchronized` same Exception.

And this is the `HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error`

> java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
>
> > java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:901)
> >     java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:851)
> >     servlets.AddCart.doGet(AddCart.java:36)
> >     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
> >     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
> >     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

Comment: Tried googeling that error message?

Comment: Yes, but I didn't help. I've already tried ListIterators. I've been trying for more than 1 hour to solve. I understand the problem is the Iterator, but when I call the Servlet isn't it set to the beginning of the list again?

Comment: It would tell you something about not changing the list while iterating it...

Comment: Oh now I understand the problem. I don't know why I didn't noticed it before

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't add an item to a list you are iterating with an enhanced for loop. This is because you are modifying the internal state of the list; whilst it is possible to handle this, most iterator implementations don't handle state changes of the underlying collection, in order to stay simple for the vast, vast majority of use cases.

Instead of this:

```
for (Product p1 : previousItems) {
    previousItems.add(p); // Simplified
}
```

If you want `p` to be in the list after, put it into another list, then add that list after iteration:

```
List<Product> other = new ArrayList<>();
for (Product p1 : previousItems) {
    other.add(p);
}
previousItems.addAll(other);
```

Comment: I think this is like the very first time that I refrain from giving an answer to give a comment instead - as I guess there should be plenty of duplicates for example.... To then find an answer from you. Normally it worked the other way round. But nice precise answer.

Answer (score 1):

This exception is expected when you modify `ArrayList` inside of `for` loop. Internally, `for` loop uses `Iterator` and modification of non thread safe collections during iteration is not allowed. You can read [this](http://www.journaldev.com/378/java-util-concurrentmodificationexception) article to find out more.

But, I'd recommend to change your logic the following way:

```
if (p != null) {
  // Check if previousItems already contains the product
  if (!previousItems.contains(p)) {
    // If it doesn't, add the product
    previousItems.add(p);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it was so easy. I added a `break` after the `previousItems.add(p)` inside the `for loop`. If I use your solution I still have to use a `for loop` to find the Product. So if I leave like it is is better?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot update a list that you are iterating, this cause ConcurrentModificationException

```
for (Product p1 : previousItems) {
    previousItems.add(p); //you cant update the previousItems list here
}
```

Instead what you can do is:

```
ArrayList<Product> auxList = new ArrayList<>();
for (Product p1 : previousItems) {
    //...
    //else...
        auxList.add(p);
}
```

and after:

```
previousItems.addAll(auxList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use, CopyOnWriteArrayList instead of ArrayList if you just want to avoid ConcurrentModificationException.